# Gcc Eclipse checking

Tags: xcode, eclipse, gcc, osx-lion, llvm-gcc

I use eclipse for C/C++ programming on a macOS Lion. Recently I've installed the new gcc version, gcc-mp-4.7, with macPorts. Then I have substituted this new version with the older one, the default X-code 4.2.1, using the port select command.
Now from command line I can see that I'm using the new gcc version.

How can I check if Eclipse is using this new version? From toolchain I see just the older versions of gcc installed (like llvm-gcc4.2). If I write gcc in the Build options command line, will Eclipse take the changed version or the old one?

Maybe this is a silly question, but I haven't seen anything clear in the web :)